# javascript foreach find and update

Tags: javascript, foreach, find, lodash

Let say I have an array of tree type data

```
[ { 'id': 1, 'name': 'root', 'parent_id': 1 },
  { 'id': 2, 'name': 'level 1', 'parent_id': 1 },
  { 'id': 3, 'name': 'level 2', 'parent_id': 1 },
  { 'id': 4, 'name': 'level 2.1', 'parent_id': 3 } ]
```

is it possible to update the array to

```
[ { 'id': 1, 'name': 'root', 'parent_id': 1, 'parent_name': 'root' },
  { 'id': 2, 'name': 'level 1', 'parent_id': 1, 'parent_name': 'root' },
  { 'id': 3, 'name': 'level 2', 'parent_id': 1, 'parent_name': 'root' },
  { 'id': 4, 'name': 'level 2.1', 'parent_id': 3, 'parent_name': 'level 2' } ]
```

using lodash forEach and find?

```
_.forEach(arr, function (o) {
  let item = _.find(arr, {'id': o.parent_id})
  o.parent_name = item.name
})
```

**my problem is inside the function of forEach, it has no idea what arr is**, I got it working replacing the forEach with a plain for loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let item = _.find(arr, {'id': arr[i].parent_id})
  arr[i].parent_name = item.name
}
```

So wondering if there're any more elegant way to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to solve your problem using a hash to improve performance:

```
let hash = _.keyBy(data, 'id');
```

This will create an object where the keys are the id:

```
{
    1: { id: 1, name: 'root' ... },
    2: { id: 2, name: 'level 1' ... },
    ...
}
```

Then just iterate over the data to set the `parent_name` using the hash:

```
_.each(data, item => item.parent_name = _.get(hash, [item.parent_id, 'name']));
```

Comment: Probably the `parent_id` of one of the objects doesn't exist e.g. in your data a parent_id of 6 would return the error your getting. Have changed the code to use lodash's `get` function to cater for that case.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what happened!

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the documentation on [_.forEach](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach).

> The iteratee is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).

You need to setup your `forEach` like so:

```
_.forEach(arr, function (o, idx, arr) {
      let item = _.find(arr, {'id': o.parent_id})
      o.parent_name = item.name
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .map to change object as-

```
const arr =[ { 'id': 1, 'name': 'root', 'parent_id': 1 },
  { 'id': 2, 'name': 'level 1', 'parent_id': 1 },
  { 'id': 3, 'name': 'level 2', 'parent_id': 1 },
  { 'id': 4, 'name': 'level 2.1', 'parent_id': 3 } ];

const newArr = arr.map((item) => {
  if(name === 'root') return Object.assign({}, item, {parent_name: 'root'});
  const findIndexOfParent = arr.findIndex((pItem) => pItem.id == item.parent_id);
  if(findIndexOfParent > -1){
    return Object.assign({}, item, {parent_name: arr[findIndexOfParent].name});
  }
});

console.log(newArr);
```